# Javascript - Jquery not displaying values passed in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found this bootstrap script that allows the user to enter a review.

**Issue:** i am trying to display the comment + Name and I'm getting `undefined` for comment and how could i display the stars selected by the user?

Also Is there a way to save the comment and name so it will display all the time after hitting submit button. (Without a database)

Here is my code

```js
(function(e) {
  var t, o = {
      className: "autosizejs",
      append: "",
      callback: !1,
      resizeDelay: 10
    },
    i = '<textarea tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-999px; left:0; right:auto; bottom:auto; border:0; padding: 0; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; box-sizing:content-box; word-wrap:break-word; height:0 !important; min-height:0 !important; overflow:hidden; transition:none; -webkit-transition:none; -moz-transition:none;"/>',
    n = ["fontFamily", "fontSize", "fontWeight", "fontStyle", "letterSpacing", "textTransform", "wordSpacing", "textIndent"],
    s = e(i).data("autosize", !0)[0];
  s.style.lineHeight = "99px", "99px" === e(s).css("lineHeight") && n.push("lineHeight"), s.style.lineHeight = "", e.fn.autosize = function(i) {
    return this.length ? (i = e.extend({}, o, i || {}), s.parentNode !== document.body && e(document.body).append(s), this.each(function() {
      function o() {
        var t, o;
        "getComputedStyle" in window ? (t = window.getComputedStyle(u, null), o = u.getBoundingClientRect().width, e.each(["paddingLeft", "paddingRight", "borderLeftWidth", "borderRightWidth"], function(e, i) {
          o -= parseInt(t[i], 10)
        }), s.style.width = o + "px") : s.style.width = Math.max(p.width(), 0) + "px"
      }

      function a() {
        var a = {};
        if (t = u, s.className = i.className, d = parseInt(p.css("maxHeight"), 10), e.each(n, function(e, t) {
            a[t] = p.css(t)
          }), e(s).css(a), o(), window.chrome) {
          var r = u.style.width;
          u.style.width = "0px", u.offsetWidth, u.style.width = r
        }
      }

      function r() {
        var e, n;
        t !== u ? a() : o(), s.value = u.value + i.append, s.style.overflowY = u.style.overflowY, n = parseInt(u.style.height, 10), s.scrollTop = 0, s.scrollTop = 9e4, e = s.scrollTop, d && e > d ? (u.style.overflowY = "scroll", e = d) : (u.style.overflowY = "hidden", c > e && (e = c)), e += w, n !== e && (u.style.height = e + "px", f && i.callback.call(u, u))
      }

      function l() {
        clearTimeout(h), h = setTimeout(function() {
          var e = p.width();
          e !== g && (g = e, r())
        }, parseInt(i.resizeDelay, 10))
      }
      var d, c, h, u = this,
        p = e(u),
        w = 0,
        f = e.isFunction(i.callback),
        z = {
          height: u.style.height,
          overflow: u.style.overflow,
          overflowY: u.style.overflowY,
          wordWrap: u.style.wordWrap,
          resize: u.style.resize
        },
        g = p.width();
      p.data("autosize") || (p.data("autosize", !0), ("border-box" === p.css("box-sizing") || "border-box" === p.css("-moz-box-sizing") || "border-box" === p.css("-webkit-box-sizing")) && (w = p.outerHeight() - p.height()), c = Math.max(parseInt(p.css("minHeight"), 10) - w || 0, p.height()), p.css({
        overflow: "hidden",
        overflowY: "hidden",
        wordWrap: "break-word",
        resize: "none" === p.css("resize") || "vertical" === p.css("resize") ? "none" : "horizontal"
      }), "onpropertychange" in u ? "oninput" in u ? p.on("input.autosize keyup.autosize", r) : p.on("propertychange.autosize", function() {
        "value" === event.propertyName && r()
      }) : p.on("input.autosize", r), i.resizeDelay !== !1 && e(window).on("resize.autosize", l), p.on("autosize.resize", r), p.on("autosize.resizeIncludeStyle", function() {
        t = null, r()
      }), p.on("autosize.destroy", function() {
        t = null, clearTimeout(h), e(window).off("resize", l), p.off("autosize").off(".autosize").css(z).removeData("autosize")
      }), r())
    })) : this
  }
})(window.jQuery || window.$);

var __slice = [].slice;
(function(e, t) {
  var n;
  n = function() {
    function t(t, n) {
      var r, i, s, o = this;
      this.options = e.extend({}, this.defaults, n);
      this.$el = t;
      s = this.defaults;
      for (r in s) {
        i = s[r];
        if (this.$el.data(r) != null) {
          this.options[r] = this.$el.data(r)
        }
      }
      this.createStars();
      this.syncRating();
      this.$el.on("mouseover.starrr", "span", function(e) {
        return o.syncRating(o.$el.find("span").index(e.currentTarget) + 1)
      });
      this.$el.on("mouseout.starrr", function() {
        return o.syncRating()
      });
      this.$el.on("click.starrr", "span", function(e) {
        return o.setRating(o.$el.find("span").index(e.currentTarget) + 1)
      });
      this.$el.on("starrr:change", this.options.change)
    }
    t.prototype.defaults = {
      rating: void 0,
      numStars: 5,
      change: function(e, t) {}
    };
    t.prototype.createStars = function() {
      var e, t, n;
      n = [];
      for (e = 1, t = this.options.numStars; 1 <= t ? e <= t : e >= t; 1 <= t ? e++ : e--) {
        n.push(this.$el.append("<span class='glyphicon .glyphicon-star-empty'></span>"))
      }
      return n
    };
    t.prototype.setRating = function(e) {
      if (this.options.rating === e) {
        e = void 0
      }
      this.options.rating = e;
      this.syncRating();
      return this.$el.trigger("starrr:change", e)
    };
    t.prototype.syncRating = function(e) {
      var t, n, r, i;
      e || (e = this.options.rating);
      if (e) {
        for (t = n = 0, i = e - 1; 0 <= i ? n <= i : n >= i; t = 0 <= i ? ++n : --n) {
          this.$el.find("span").eq(t).removeClass("glyphicon-star-empty").addClass("glyphicon-star")
        }
      }
      if (e && e < 5) {
        for (t = r = e; e <= 4 ? r <= 4 : r >= 4; t = e <= 4 ? ++r : --r) {
          this.$el.find("span").eq(t).removeClass("glyphicon-star").addClass("glyphicon-star-empty")
        }
      }
      if (!e) {
        return this.$el.find("span").removeClass("glyphicon-star").addClass("glyphicon-star-empty")
      }
    };
    return t
  }();
  return e.fn.extend({
    starrr: function() {
      var t, r;
      r = arguments[0], t = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
      return this.each(function() {
        var i;
        i = e(this).data("star-rating");
        if (!i) {
          e(this).data("star-rating", i = new n(e(this), r))
        }
        if (typeof r === "string") {
          return i[r].apply(i, t)
        }
      })
    }
  })
})(window.jQuery, window);
$(function() {
  return $(".starrr").starrr()
})

$(function() {

  $('#new-review').autosize({
    append: "\n"
  });

  var reviewBox = $('#post-review-box');
  var newReview = $('#new-review');
  var openReviewBtn = $('#open-review-box');
  var closeReviewBtn = $('#close-review-box');
  var ratingsField = $('#ratings-hidden');

  openReviewBtn.click(function(e) {
    reviewBox.slideDown(400, function() {
      $('#new-review').trigger('autosize.resize');
      newReview.focus();
    });
    openReviewBtn.fadeOut(100);
    closeReviewBtn.show();
  });

  closeReviewBtn.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    reviewBox.slideUp(300, function() {
      newReview.focus();
      openReviewBtn.fadeIn(200);
    });
    closeReviewBtn.hide();

  });

  $('.starrr').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {
    ratingsField.val(value);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname: "required",
      comment: "required",

    },
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your first name",
      comment: "Please enter your Comment",
    }
  });

  $('#form').submit(function() {
    if ($('#form').valid()) {
      var str = '';
      str += $('#firstname').val() + '<br />';
      str += $('#comment').val() + '<br />';
      $('.display').append(str);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.2s;
}

.stars {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #d17581;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="text-right">
          <a class="btn btn-success btn-green" href="#reviews-anchor" id="open-review-box">Leave a Review</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="post-review-box" style="display:none;">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <form id="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post">
              <input type="text" class="form-control animated" name="firstname" id="firstname" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter your Name">
              <br>
              <input id="ratings-hidden" name="rating" type="hidden">
              <textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" id="new-review" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5"></textarea>

              <div class="text-right">
                <div class="stars starrr" data-rating="0"></div>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#" id="close-review-box" style="display:none; margin-right: 10px;">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</a>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="display"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check the webiste here [here](https://tadzik9634.000webhostapp.com/index.php)

Comment: As you are getting value from `str += $('#comment').val() + '<br />';`, but seems `#comment` this id is not available in your form there is `id="new-review" ` that should be `id="comment" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your javascript code says to select textarea with id `comment`

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($('#form').valid()) {
  var str = '';
  str += $('#firstname').val() + '<br />';
  str += $('#comment').val() + '<br />';
  $('.display').append(str);
}
return false;
});
```

Change the id of textarea from `new-review` to `comment`

```
<textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: Simple mistake cost me an hour. thanks for spoting that out!